# Showing autocompletetextview adapter continuously even after clicked on the list item ??

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, simpleadapter

I'm working on the **autocomplete textview** concept it works fine on emulator when it is checked in mobile it is always showing dropdown list even after tapping the listitem.Please help me out from this issue.

[image]